# pip is only instaling to the default python instaltion how can i chnage it

Tags: python

i created a new project in pycharm.  it created a new installation of python in a folder called myproject\vin.

pip will allways go to the default  installation at

```
c:\\python64bit,
not c:\test\vin
```

example in my if i go import pandas it says that module does not exist.
if i go pip install pandas, it says
You should consider upgrading via the `'python -m pip install --upgrade pip'` command.

```
PS C:\Users\tpottel\programming\java\eclipse projects\BBitBotCoinUsing2\untitled1\venv\Scripts> pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\python64bit\lib\site-packages (0.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in c:\python64bit\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\python64bit\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.17.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\python64bit\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2019.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\python64bit\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas) (1.1  

c:\python64bit is the default location

How can I change the installation pip will update? to
 C:\Users\tpottel\programming\java\eclipse projects\BBitBotCoinUsing2\untitled1\venv\Scripts>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few ways you might find more robust for managing multiple python installations on one machine such as creating a virtual environment (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/installing-multiple-python-versions-on-windows-using-virtualenv/) but ignoring that, here's one way you could go about it.

There's two facts you'll need to know and work around for this, firstly, I think you'll need to make sure that you second python installation is added to path in order to call 'pip' from your terminal/command line.

Second is that python searches through installations in order, by finding the python.exe file. This means that with:

```
pip install pandas
```

which, it's worth nothing is shorthand for:

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

it will find the first python.exe based on a hierarchy and install to there, which is why you're not able to install to your second distribution.

If you rename the second distributions .exe to something like 'python64.exe' you can call it specifically with

```
python64 -m pip install pandas
```

hopefully that should help! Again, there might be a better way of acheiving this, but this is one method that should work.